# Why is this JQuery popup reappearing?

Tags: jquery, each

I have a JQuery popup function that shows some text when users click a link.  They click "Close" to close the pop-up.  Pretty straight forward.

The problem is the pop-up reappears immediately after it is closed.

Here's the problem bit:

```
JAVACRIPT
$.fn.myPopup = function(popupText)
{
    var popupHtml = '<div class="messagepop pop">' + popupText + '<p align="right"><a class="close" href="#">Close</a></div>';
    this.each(function()
    {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("selected").parent().append(popupHtml);
            $(".pop").slideFadeToggle()
       });
        return false;
    });

    $(".close").on('click', function() 
    {
        alert('in close function - about to do slideFadeToggle on: ' + popupText);
        $(".pop").slideFadeToggle();
        alert('just did slideFadeToggle, about to removeClass on: ' + popupText);        
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
        alert('just did removeClass on: ' + popupText);
    });

    return this;
};
$("#word1234").myPopup("Lorem Ipsum");
$("#wordABCD").myPopup("Hello World");


HTML
<a href="#" id="word1234">Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</a> <br>
<a href="#" id="wordABCD">Foo</a> <br>
```

Here's a fiddle so you can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/N4QCZ/3/

Why is the popup reappearing after it successfully closes?

Comment: I don't see any popup, instead a js error "slideFadeToggle is not a function".

Comment: I had to change the fiddle to use jQuery 1.9.1 instead of 1.4RC4 to get the fiddle to work at all.

Comment: The problem is that you're binding `$(".close").on('click', ...)` before the popup is added to the DOM, so there's nothing to bind to. You need to delegate rather than bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't stopping event propagation on the close click, and since close is within the element that triggers the popup it works its way down, triggering the popup click handler as well.  Call http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/ within the the click handler for close.

**EDIT**

Actually you append it to the parent, so it shouldn't trigger the second click, but I'd call stop propagation anyway.  Another problem is probably this line within both the close handler and the popup handler: `$(".pop").slideFadeToggle();`

This will cause ALL of the popups you've generated to slideToggle, meaning that once you've created more than one (which you do) then on each call the hidden ones will show and the shown ones will hide.  Also, is slideFadeToggle a custom plugin? sure you didn't mean slideToggle() ?

**SECOND EDIT**

This line within close is also problematic: `$(this).removeClass("selected");`

Readup on this and jQuery this, because within the callback this referes to the clicked element (.close) not the element that you added the class 'selected' to earlier.

Comment: Something is being left in memory after the first click happens.  When the second click happens, if it's a different item, both popups are triggered, with one function call.  http://jsfiddle.net/N4QCZ/9/

Comment: The issue is that you still have the problem discussed in my first Edit

Comment: I learn best by examples - skimmed over your text and went for the code posted by Jai.  Now I see what you're saying.  Off to work on that now.

Comment: Negatory.  Both popups appear.

Comment: oh, I forgot to update the fiddle, I thought they did so live.

Comment: Fiddle is crawling this afternoon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24400/discussion-between-runspired-and-a-coder)

Answer (score 2):

as `@runspired` mentioned in his answer: http://jsfiddle.net/N4QCZ/5/

```
$(document).on('click', ".close", function(e) { //<-----event delegation needed here
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //<-----you need this
    $(".pop").slideFadeToggle();
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```